# Shadows/lighting not working with image texture

Tags: texturing, game-engine, light

I've been trying to texture a planet with a spherical image that I have. I did a UV unwrap of the sphere and created a new material, then created a new image texture and selected a UV map using map I just created. However, the backside of the planet still seems to be lit when I run the game with the textures turned on, even though without textures, the shading seems to work. These two images are from the same view. Any ideas?

[image: Shading without texture]

[image: Shading with texture]

Comment: What are your material settings like? Do you have shadows enabled? I do seem to remember there being a bug with image textures in the BGE . . . there was a setting I forgot to turn on, but I can't remember which.

Comment: Actually, I was able to figure it out finally. It had to do with GLSL shading settings not being quite right. Thanks though!

Comment: Go ahead and add it as an answer then :)